# Cannot send or receive messages via TCP

Tags: c#, .net, tcp

I keep getting:

> A first chance exception of type 'System.Net.Sockets.SocketException'
>   occurred in System.dll System.Net.Sockets.SocketException
>   (0x80004005): No connection could be made because the target machine
>   actively refused it 911.00.00.666:13000

even after I allow the app through the Windows Firewall. I've also tried ports 80, 8080 and 13000.

Why does this always happen? How do I fix it?

I am following this tutorial: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcpclient(v=vs.110).aspx#Y2523

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace TCPTestClient
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        String msgToSend = "Hello, dude.";

        private void button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                Int32 port = 13000;

                TcpClient client = new TcpClient("localhost", port);

                Byte[] data = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(msgToSend);

                NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();
                stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);

                Console.WriteLine("Send: {0}", msgToSend);

                data = new Byte[256];

                String response = String.Empty;

                Int32 bytes = stream.Read(data, 0, data.Length);
                response = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data, 0, bytes);
                Console.WriteLine("Received: {0}", response);

                title.Text = response;

                stream.Close();
                client.Close();
            }
            catch (ArgumentNullException ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex);
            }
            catch (SocketException s)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(s);
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Done");
            // All done.
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What kind of IP is this `911.00.00.666`?

Comment: Make absolutely sure that port 13000 is open to accept messages, otherwise it will fail. Also, you might as well use the actually local address (as a string) and not "localhost".

Comment: @L.B I changed it 'cause I'm paranoid. :-)

Comment: @ChristopherBales Thank you. I'm not sure how to check that, but I'm looking it up now.

Comment: @ChristopherBales I did originally try my actual local address, but that resulted in the same exception being thrown.

Comment: I just changed it to my Default Gateway address, and now I get the "A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond" error. am I getting closer?

Comment: @shane Can you post the server code as well?

Comment: The server code is exactly as shown here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.aspx

Answer (score 1):

The linked documentation assumes there is a server running and accepting connections on the port in question. Your code is just a client. It needs a server to connect to.

See the [`Socket`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.aspx) class for information on how to run a server.

Comment: Thanks. The only way I can get the linked code to work is if I use "localhost" as the hostname; which is kinda pointless, really. Is there anything else that could be blocking the connection?

Comment: @shane: it sounds like you need to do a little bit of reading about networking in general to make this click for you. "localhost" just refers to the computer on which the code is running. If you want to connect to a different host, you need to run the server on a different machine and then point the client code at that host.

Comment: Yeah, I know that. But right now I'm just trying to send messages to myself with the server/client, but even that fails. But you're right, I do need to learn a lot more.